# Append data into new excel sheet with openpyxl

Tags: python, append, openpyxl

I have bunch of excel workbooks and I would like to get cell values from them and write to a new sheet.

My code is not appending new data.It is just overwriting cells with values from last workbook.

(I've changed the pasted code.It was pasted incorrect.)

Here is my code

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

booklist = ["17_02.xlsx", "17_03.xlsx",
        "17_04.xlsx", "17_05.xlsx",
        "17_06.xlsx", "17_08.xlsx",
        "17_09.xlsx", "17_10.xlsx"]


for wb in booklist:
    book = load_workbook(filename =wb,data_only=True)
    report = load_workbook(filename="dest.xlsx", data_only=True)
    print(book)
    sheet = book['Sheet']
    reportsheet=report['First']
    row_count=sheet.max_row
    column_count=sheet.max_column
    for r in range(1,row_count+1):
        for c in range(1,column_count+1):
           source=sheet.cell(row=r, column=c)
           dest = reportsheet.cell(row=r, column=c)
           dest.value = source.value
           sheet.title = 'First'
           book.save("dest.xlsx")
```

Edit:

After the mickNeill's answer I changed the code and it worked for appending.But now there is another problem.
If I run the code (after clearing the cells) second time or more it's appending the data to the rows after the cleared cells.

First run:
Data appended to A1:A20
Clear the cells,save and close the workbook.

Second run:
Data appended to A21:A20 instead of A1:A20 (cleared cells)

Every time I run the code  value of the reportRow continues to increase (1,20,40 ...) and appending data to higher number of rows.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook


booklist = ["17_02.xlsx", "17_03.xlsx",
    "17_04.xlsx", "17_05.xlsx",
    "17_06.xlsx", "17_08.xlsx",
    "17_09.xlsx", "17_10.xlsx"]


for wb in booklist:
    book = load_workbook(filename =wb,data_only=True)
    report = load_workbook(filename="dest.xlsx", data_only=True)
    print(book)
    sheet = book['Sheet']
    reportsheet=report['First']
    row_count=sheet.max_row
    reportRow = reportsheet.max_row
    column_count=sheet.max_column
    for r in range(1,row_count+2):
        for c in range(1,column_count+1):
            source=sheet.cell(row=r, column=c)
            dest = reportsheet.cell(row=reportRow, column=c)
            dest.value = source.value
        reportRow += 1
    report.save("dest.xlsx")
```

Comment: row_count is getting reset on each workbook.  Every time you go to the next book, it starts at row 1 again

Comment: r needs to be set to the next blank row in report workbook

Comment: @mickNeill row_count must start at row 1 to read from beginning of the new sheet.

Comment: right but you are also writing to the dest workbook at row 1

Comment: are you trying to write each book to a new sheet or all on the same sheet in "dest.xlsx"?

Comment: all on the same sheet

Answer (score 1):

Try this: Editied, you are saving the wrong book, last line

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

booklist = ["Book5.xlsx", "Book6.xlsx","Book7.xlsx"]

report = load_workbook(filename="dest.xlsx", data_only=True)
for wb in booklist:
    book = load_workbook(filename =wb,data_only=True)

    #print(book)
    sheet = book['Sheet1']
    reportsheet=report['First']
    row_count=sheet.max_row
    reportRow = reportsheet.max_row + 1
    print reportRow
    column_count=sheet.max_column
    for r in range(1,row_count+1):
        for c in range(1,column_count+1):
            print reportRow
            source=sheet.cell(row=r, column=c)
            dest = reportsheet.cell(row=reportRow, column=c)
            dest.value = source.value
            sheet.title = 'First' 
        reportRow += 1
report.save("dest.xlsx")
```

Comment: you are saving the books in the list, not the destination file

Comment: Load the report book once, and save it once

Comment: After running the code I've cleared  the cells (A1:A20) in the sheet and ran it again.This time it appended the data into the cells (A21:A40) after the cells (A1:A20) that first run appended data and I cleared.

Comment: Not sure what the issue is, it runs for me every time.    If you are only clearing column A and there is data in any other column, that will be the max row and it will start from there and not from row 1.

Comment: reportRow value still remains and when running the code again it starts from the value in the memory not from the 1.

Comment: if you use the code above and change the book list, this will work.  If "dest.xlsx" is completely empty, it will start from row 2 (for headers) and continue. To start at row 1, make `reportRow =  reportsheet.max_row`.  If dest.xlsx has any data in it it will start at that row.

Comment: Unless you really need to load a workbook, this could be avoided by creating a new workbook for the destination file and writing to that.

Comment: Can you create a new book every time? Instead of loading a current workbook

Comment: I don't want to write data into separate wb or sheets. From many wb to one  and one exact sheet.

Comment: I am not sure what the issue is because the code works for me every time.

Comment: It doesn't start to write from the last row if active sheet has data in it.Just overwriting from the first row.